# Replacing DOM Nodes with new nodes.

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a collection of DOM nodes I would like to replace with new DOM nodes. 
Due to the way I pass the information into the function I only have a variable named collection which is an object full of HtmlTableRowElements and I would like to replace it with a new variable called Rows.

Here is what I have

```
var parent = collection[0].parentNode;
parent.innerHTML = "";
parent.appendChild(rows);
```

however this gives me a long strange error.

> uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMHTMLTableSectionElement.appendChild]" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: http://127.0.0.1/test.php ::  :: line 103" data: no]

So I have also tried

```
collection[0].parentNode.innerHTML = "";
collection[0].parentNode.appendChild(rows);
```

which returns

> collection[0].parentNode is null

I do understand why the second option is returning an error. I would imagine the first option is returning an error because I have removed the element the variable is referencing.

I'm beginning to think that looking for the parent and replacing it's contents is not the way to go about this.

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is in `rows`? I can't tell from your question

- If it’s an array, put the contents into a document fragment and append that:

  ```
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l, i++) {
      fragment.appendChild(rows[i]);
  }

  parent.appendChild(fragment);
  ```

  Putting a bunch of elements in a document fragment is faster than appending them to something in the document one by one, and is a good way to carry around a collection of elements (instead of an array).
- If it’s a string, use `innerHTML`:

  ```
  parent.innerHTML = rows;
  ```

---

When you call `collection[0].parentNode.innerHTML = ""`, collection gets removed from the document. It still exists only because you’re holding onto it in a JavaScript variable, but no longer has a parent node. You should still be able to grab `parent` in advance (like you do in the first example), and append things to it:

```
var parent = collection[0].parentNode;
parent.innerHTML = "";
parent.appendChild(rows);
```

Comment: rows is an array of objects. However it is already removed from the DOM so I don't know why I would need a DocumentFragment, the only benefit I can see from this is that I can append a single child to the parent, however I still need to loop through the rows to build the child. Upvote, but the Check will have to goto Felix due to the fact that it works and it is optimized for performance.

Comment: @rlemon A document fragment is like an array that only holds DOM nodes. You can't use `appendChild` with an array, but you can use it with a document fragment.

Comment: I understand. However my list is an array, so how would I benefit from moving the array to a document fragment (by iterating through the array, adding element by element) then appending it to the DOM, versus just iterating through the array and appending the contained DOM elements to the DOM individually.

Comment: @rlemon: Replied before I saw your edit :). Using a document fragment (like in my code) actually performs much, much better than using a loop to append them individually. See [this blog post by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) for details.

Comment: You are correct. Just ran a performance test on it (and for my project) using a document fragment on average runs 15% faster

Answer (score 1):

`parent.innerHTML = "";` is one way to clear the content. You then have to iterate over the other elements and append them:

```
for(var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
    parent.appendChild(row[i]);
}
```

But afaik it might be problematic to append new rows this way. It might be better to use [`table.insertRow` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.insertRow).

Comment: Thankyou, I had read somewhere that if the node being appended was a nodelist it would append all nodes in the list. strange, ohh well this works and it doubles my performance speeds from the JQuery solution I was using.

Comment: @rlemon: You either do not remember correctly or the information was wrong. This does not work with NodeLists unfortunately. Only if you have a *document fragment*, all its children are inserted instead.

Comment: probably wrong information. I don't trust this thing they call the internet.